# updating ios app from ipa-file issue

Tags: ios, iphone, angularjs, hybrid-mobile-app, ipa

I have created a hybrid app with angular and ionic. The iOS version is  using Enterprise Deployment.

In the app I have made an update function, that checks if there is a new version of the ios-app. If a new version is found, it will "document.open()" the .plist belonging to the app, which is placed on my web-server. The .ipa-file is then downloaded and starts the update of my app.

So basically it works. The problem I'm having is, that the update stops at ca. 75% done. Because the update is affecting the app currently in use, ios waits for the app to be closed before finishing the last 25% of the update. I'm not allowed to close the app programmatically, because iOS don't allow this.

So what happens is that the user must click my function "check for updates" and accept to install the new version. And when they do, they should not have to do more, and the app should handle the rest. But the App can't handle the update yet, because it needs to be closed first. So i fear this to become a very confusing update function, and i would like some other solution than displaying an alert telling the user to close the app to finish the update.

Does this make sense, and does anyone know any kind of solution to my problem?

Comment: have you solved this problem ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I should implement a similar use case, and i'm worried it can't be done...